# Is there a Ruby one-liner to join() nested Ruby arrays, with different join() string for inner/outer arrays?

Tags: ruby

For:

```
a = [ ["John", "Doe"], ["Sue", "Smith"]]
```

The desired output is: `"John Doe, Sue Smith"`

The brute-force code is easy:

```
a = [ ["John", "Doe"], ["Sue", "Smith"]]
name_array = []
a.each { |n| name_array << n.join(" ") } # first, inner join w/ space
s = name_array.join(", ") # then, outer join with comma
```

But is there a more succint (one-liner?) to accomplish this in Ruby?

Comment: In that case you can use the map version instead of each plus << (`a.map { |e| e.join(' ') }.join(', ')`).

Comment: cool! happy to accept that if you post it as an answer

Comment: You can turn *any* Ruby code into a one-liner, since there are *always* alternatives to newlines. Either a different expression separator (e.g. `;`) or a keyword (e.g. `if foo then bar else baz end`). In your case: `a = [ ["John", "Doe"], ["Sue", "Smith"]]; name_array = []; a.each { |n| name_array << n.join(" ") }; s = name_array.join(", ")`. Et voila: one line, as requested.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, one more way: `(name_array = []) && (a.each { |n| name_array << n.join(" ") }) && name_array.join(", ") #=> "John Doe, Sue Smith, Melba Jones"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = [["John", "Doe"], ["Sue", "Smith"], ["Melba", "Jones"]]
```

The obvious way of doing this, that has been mentioned by others, is:

```
a.map { |arr| arr.join(' ') }.join(', ')
  #=> "John Doe, Sue Smith, Melba Jones"
```

As an exercise, here are three ways this can be done without using `Array#map`

**Use [Enumerable#reduce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`)**

```
a.drop(1).reduce(a.first.join(' ')) { |s,name| s + ", %s %s" % name }
  #=> "John Doe, Sue Smith, Melba Jones"
```

**Use recursion**

```
def doit((name, *rest))
  rest.empty? ? name.join(' ') : "%s %s, %s" % [*name, doit(rest)]
end
doit(a)
  #=> "John Doe, Sue Smith, Melba Jones"
```

**Flatten, join with a space, use [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) to insert commas**

```
r = /
    \w+[ ]\w+ # match two words separated by a space
    (?=[ ])   # positive lookahead asserts that next character is a space
    \K        # reset start of match to current location and discard all
              # previously matched characters from match that is returned
    /x        # free-spacing regex definition mode

a.flatten.join(' ').gsub(r, ',')
  #=> "John Doe, Sue Smith, Melba Jones"
```

Answer (score 2):

### Map and Join

You can do this with [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-map) and [Array#join](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-join). For example, in Ruby 2.7.1:

```
array = [["John", "Doe"], ["Sue", "Smith"]]
array.map { _1.join ?\s }.join ", "
#=> "John Doe, Sue Smith"
```

If you aren't using a recent Ruby, or find a more explicit syntax preferrable, you can do the same thing like so:

```
array.map { |subarray| subarray.join " " }.join ", "
#=> "John Doe, Sue Smith"
```

There are certainly other ways to do this, but this one-liner seems to fit your examples and use case.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to construct a new array from an existing array (or any enumerable) really what you want to use is [Enumerable#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map).

Map iterates over your existing array, runs the block, and collects the results.

```rb
 result = a.map { |people| people.join(' ') }.join(', ')
```

Broken down:

```rb
intermediate = a.map { |people| people.join(' ') } 
# transforms
#   [ ["John", "Doe"], ["Sue", "Smith"]]
# into
#   [ "John Doe", "Sue Smith" ]
# we take the result of that and run
result = intermediate.join(', ')
# which then transforms your array in the the final string:
# "John Doe, Sue Smith"
```